# Pick values to Component from array within array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

The user has own list of tags and each item owned by the user can have multiple tags from this tag list.

Here I am trying to map all the users tags for one item and if the specific item has a tag from the userTag list then those tag Chip element should have a different style aqua coloured background.

I am struggling on finding a way to get the 'tag: array' values and implementing the Chip element style accordingly to multiple tags. Here I can only get the item.tag array for the first tag item.tag[0]. How would I go by when trying to get each value from the nested tag array inside itemsData and give the item multiple aqua coloured tags if it has multiple tags.

[image: example]

```
 const itemsData = [
 { id: 1, tag: ['Fysik', 'Matematik'] },
 { id: 2, tag: ['Analytics', 'Marketing', 'Data'] },
 { id: 3, tag: [''] },
 ];
```

```
<div>
  {userTags.map(tag => (
    <Chip
      label={tag}
      variant={item.tag[0] === tag ? 'default' : 'outlined'}
      onClick={() => { onTagSelected(tag, item.id); }}
    />
  ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <div>
      {userTags.map(tag => (
        <Chip
          label={tag}
          variant={item.tag.includes(tag) ? 'default' : 'outlined'}
          onClick={() => { onTagSelected(tag, item.id); }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to determine whether it is in the item's tag array or not.

```
<div>
  {userTags.map(tag => (
    <Chip
      label={tag}
      variant={item.tag.indexOf(tag) > -1 ? 'default' : 'outlined'}
      onClick={() => { onTagSelected(tag, item.id); }}
    />
  ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if *some* of the items tags *includes* the tag:

```
 itemsData.some(item => item.tag.includes(tag))
```

If you do that check more often on a large dataset it might be benefitial to build up a Set, then lookup is O(1):

```
 // Build up the Set once
 const highlightedTags = new Set(itemsData.flatMap(item => item.tag));

 // Then lookup:
 highlightedTags.has(tag)
```

Comment: Set seems overkill since the number of tags for an item wouldn't be a large dataset.